# Issue with encoding objects on iOS Device

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm making an app that uses **encoding** to ***store objects*** on the document directory,

On iOS Simulator, the objects are getting saved perfectly, and if i closed the app and got back to it all the data are restored with no issue.

But today i tried my app on the iPhone 5s, the objects are not getting saved when i close the app and go back to it again all the data are getting removed only on the real device, what is the problem ?

I'm using this method to get the directory path:

```
- (NSString *)pathForTask
{
NSArray *documentDirectories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentDirectory = [documentDirectories firstObject];
return [documentDirectory stringByAppendingString:@"Tasks"];
}
```

Archive:

```
NSString *path = [self pathForTask]; 
[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:self.privateTasks toFile:path];
```

Unarchive:

```
NSString *path = [self pathForTask]; 
_privateTasks = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:path];
```

Comment: Can you post the code you're using to get the documents directory?

Comment: @socaljoker

- (NSString *)pathForTask
{
    NSArray *documentDirectories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentDirectory = [documentDirectories firstObject];
    return [documentDirectory stringByAppendingString:@"Tasks"];
}

Comment: On iOS, paths are case-sensitive... but if you use the above routine to get the file, then it should be ok. Have you downloaded the container from the device to check if the file is being created and anything in it?

Comment: @Raff7M Don't put code in comments. Update your question with relevant details so people see it and can read it.

Comment: thanks for clearing that out @rmaddy

Comment: Can you print out your paths on the simulator and device and add it to your question? Also make sure there isn't a file with bad data at the path on the device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following line of code is causing your problem:

```
return [documentDirectory stringByAppendingString:@"Tasks"];
```

The results in the returned path being something like:

```
.../DocumentsTasks
```

Note the lack of a slash.

Change the line to:

```
return [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Tasks"];
```

This will return a proper path and your code will work on a device.

It works in the simulator because you end up creating a file named `DocumentTasks` in some folder on your computer. But on a real device, the folder that this file is trying to be written to is read-only due to sandboxing.

Comment: that's what happens when you let xcode complete code for you XD, Thanks it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the documents directory using the following code instead:

```
- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory
{
    return [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
}
```

After getting the documents directory, you can get the path to a specific file by doing:

```
NSURL *fileURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"[FILE NAME]"];
```

I'm not sure why your code doesn't work, but this is the code I use on my app and it works in the simulator and the physical device.

Comment: The same issue, is it a bug on iOS 8.1 ? because the iPhone 5s is on iOS 8.1 and the simulator is on iOS 8.3.

Comment: I doubt it. I've been using that code since iOS 6.x I believe.

Comment: You're welcome. Sorry I couldn't be of any more help.

Answer (score 0):

Frequently code that works on the sim but not on the device is caused by filename upper/lower case mismatching.

The file system in Mac OS is almost always case-insenstive. (You can use disk volumes who's file system are case sensitive in Mac OS, but they are not by default.)

The simulator runs on Mac OS. It's file system is not case sensitive. So if you save a file as "Tasks" and then load it as "tasks" it works on the sim, but not on an actual iOS device. Make sure you check really carefully for mismatched case in your filenames.

Comment: don't think it's related to the case-sensetive or not because I'm archiving and unarchiving like the code in the question.

Comment: I guess not then. (Note that code in comments is all but impossible to read. Better to edit your original question and add code at the end.) @rmaddy's suggestion of using stringByAppendingPathComponent is another likely cause, although I don't know why it would work on the sim but not on an iOS device.

Comment: @DuncanC I explain in my answer why it works in the sim and not on the device.